# книги по Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Здравствуйте, хочу ознакомиться с Hibernate , но книги в основном   2010 года выпуска или еще раньше , можете посоветовать  более актуальные книги на русском по hibernate.

Comment: Не книги интересуют?

Comment: Prototype - TV меня интересуют книги , желательно не старые и на русском

Comment: Самая свежая и толковая книга по Hibernate - это ["Beginning Hibernate"](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430265184), а на русском ничего хорошего по этой теме просто не существует.